# Reading in paths with spaces from file using Windows command line FOR loop

Tags: for-loop, cmd, path, whitespace

I have a list of files in a text file that I want to delete. I am attempting to use the Windows command line FOR with DEL to accomplish this. The issue I have is that some of the paths have spaces in them. I've tried using double quotes in the text file, but the command line throws an error saying it can find the path. Example paths with errors below.

Example list of files in `d:\testfiles.txt`

```
d:\test\test_001.txt
d:\test\test_002.txt
"d:\test\test with space 001.txt"
d:\test\test with space 002.txt
```

Command line: `for /F %i in (d:\testfiles.txt) do del %i`

`test_001.txt` and `test_002.txt` are deleted ok, but command line then throws an error

```
Could Not Find d:\test\test
```

for both of the last two files.

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %i in (d:\testfiles.txt) do del "%~i"` uses the option `delims=` with an empty list of delimiters to turn off line splitting behavior completely. `for /F "eol=| delims=" %i in (d:\testfiles.txt) do del "%~i"` works also for file names in the text file without path starting with a semicolon. For more details run in command prompt window `for /?` and read the entire output help carefully from top of first to bottom of last page or use Stack Overflow search to find answers written by me using `for` and `delims` as I explain them in all my answers very detailed.

Comment: @Mofi thank you, your first suggestion worked. Reading through the output help I see the use of `delims=` and `%~`. The extra `""` around the `%~i`, is that to add the quotes back again?

Comment: Yes, for `d:\test\test with space 002.txt` in text file it is necessary to add the double quotes on passing the file name to command `del`. `%~i` removes the surrounding `"` from `"d:\test\test with space 001.txt"` as the required surrounding `"` are specified on the command line. `"` are always needed on file name string containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``.

Answer (score 0):

According to [@Mofi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63288683/reading-in-paths-with-spaces-from-file-using-windows-command-line-for-loop#comment111913536_63288683), the solution for my issue was to use:

```
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %i in ("d:\testfiles.txt") do del "%~i"
```

Comment: As it is perfectly feasible that one or more of the listed files do not exist I'd either check first, or redirect any 'could not find' messages to the NUL device, e.g. `For /F UseBackEOL^=^"Delims^=^" %I In ("D:\testfiles.txt")Do @If Exist "%I" Del /A/F "%I"` or `For /F "UseBackQ EOL=| Delims=" %I In ("D:\testfiles.txt") Do @Del "%~I" 2> NUL`.